# How to remove Text field from Form in J2ME

Tags: java-me, midp, midp-2.0

Hey Hi Friends,
                I have created one application where in one text field i am getting input from user as id and according to id i am displaying the information. At run time i am adding another text fields but suppose user inserting wrong id then i want remove all text fields from Form. it is possible to remove text fields which added previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but Form.delete(int itemNum) and Form.deleteAll() will allow you to delete Items that have been added to a Form.

See [Form](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) documentation.